# Show random image for screensaver, no slideshow

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, graphics, screensaver

Is there any way to have the screensaver show a single random image from a folder of images, but to **not** rotate the images in a slideshow?

The closest thing I can get is by selecting the "Classic" screensaver option in the "Desktop and Screensaver" settings and then selecting my folder of images as the source. However, there is no way to **prevent** the images from rotating/ showing as a slideshow/ displaying one after the other. I am so far also unable to find any app that lets me do this.

I am using a MacBook Pro running High Sierra, version 10.13.6

Comment: I placed 3 images in a new folder I created,   I used the Classic screensaver from the screensaver panel.  The 3 images were displayed one after the other and no rotation was done. All 3 images were shown as is.  I'm running High Sierra on an iMac.

Comment: They were displayed one after the other, that is my problem. One after the other = rotation/ slideshow.

Comment: A screensaver isn't what you are looking for - pretty much any screensaver will change images, because, well, they save the screen by _not_ keeping a static image.

Comment: Old CRT monitors had “burn in,” screensavers nowadays don't do anything except look pretty and use electricity...

Comment: you could do the random part yourself by placing one image in a folder and use that folder for the screen-saver.  If there is only one image it naturally doesn't rotate. Kind of a pain though, changing the image every day.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now, I have one image in a folder, and when I want it changed I manually switch it out.